# When is the upward economic convergence in the EU estimated to happen?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, economic-growth, development-economics, eu

Although the regional cohesion, i. e. the socio-economical convergence of the East and the West has been one of the EU's [main goals](https://europa.eu/european-union/about-eu/eu-in-brief_en), [some economists](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277942574_Evidence_for_economic_convergence_in_the_EU_The_analysis_of_past_EU_enlargements) seem to dispute there's any evidence for them being successful while [others claim](https://www.eurofound.europa.eu/sites/default/files/ef_publication/field_ef_document/ef19049en.pdf) it's well on its way.

However, I wasn't able to find any sources that would try to estimate when the point of economic convergence should happen. Have there been any similar analyses?

Comment: The source does not actually claim that it has happened - in fact the source itself shows there is still quite a lot of divergence only it highlights the successes in reducing that divergence

Comment: @1muflon1 You're right, sorry for this misinterpretation, I edited the question. The original link (http://dimiter.eu/Visualizations_files/CEE.html) truly doesn't explicitely advocate convergence has already happened, that was only my interpretation of data showing in some areas, some post-communist states surpassed Southern Europe.